# Image file size exceeds 700 MB

Tags: mount

I downloaded an ubuntu image file, but its size is 30 MB more than a CD can hold. Also, my computer can not boot through a DVD or USB drive; what should I do? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Really you have multiple choices:

First of all you can try a bigger Cd capacity(there are 800 MB CD's)

You can try The Network installation or Install directly from Internet.

Please check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Alternate_Installation

Here is a list alternate installations so read and choose the one that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You could download the alternate Ubuntu iso from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads):

For the Ubuntu 12.04.4 64bit [click here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)

For the Ubuntu 13.10 64bit [click here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

Answer (score 0):

Install 12.04 using Wubi

[Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

Note: This is if you running windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 will run from CD. See Ubuntu download page [here:](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)

A "700MB" CD would be a good start. They can fit 737MB on (because the advertised number is actually a MiB) and even then there's often some overburn space. I've got to over 750MB on a 700MB disk

After installing 12.04 either you can upgrade to 12.10 and so on or wait till April 17 and you can directly upgrade to 14.04LTS